# Запись данных в файл конфигураций (App.config)

Tags: c#, .net, config

Пытаюсь записать данные в конфигурационное свойство из приложения(простое консольное приложение) во время выполнения, но получаю исключение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс секции

```
public class CustomConfigurationSection: ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("culture")]
    public CultureElement Culture
    {
        get { return (CultureElement)this["culture"]; }
        set { this["culture"] = value; }
    }

}
```

Класс элемента секции

```
 public class CultureElement: ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("cultureProp")]   
    public string Culture
    {
        get { return (string)this["cultureProp"]; }
        set { this["cultureProp"] = value; }
    }

}
```

Конфигурационный файл выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код записи свойства

```
  var d = (CustomConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customSection");
        d.Culture.Culture = "ru-Ru";
```

Где я допустил ошибку, и как правильно записать данные в данное свойство?

Comment: Хм, а вы точно уверены, что можно писать в любую секцию app.config? Вроде только в configuration/appSettings можно и то не уверен. Почему не использовать стандартные Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно переопределить метод IsReadOnly в ConfigurationSection:

```
public class CustomConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }

    //...
}
```